# Set XML syntax highlighting as the default for the maven tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

I'd say, many [maven](/questions/tagged/maven)-related questions contain XML code, so it would probably make sense to have the XML formatter applied to them by default, I think? Even when the tags [maven](/questions/tagged/maven) and [java](/questions/tagged/java) are combined, I guess XML is the more common source code language in question / answer content...

Examples:

- [No manifest file from maven build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322159/no-manifest-file-from-maven-build)
- [How to inherit from a multimodule Maven project with all its goodies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245621/how-to-inherit-from-a-multimodule-maven-project-with-all-its-goodies)
- [Apache Axis2/Rampart + Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734918/apache-axis2-rampart-maven)
- [Web Service dependencies on another Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280594/webservice-dependencies-on-another-webservice) (the snippet is in the answer)

Comment: There are also questions like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287584/classnotfoundexception-on-running-maven-web-application-in-tomcat), which show a different snippet.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Yes that's what I mean by the combination of [tag:maven] and [tag:java]. In this case, Java is the wrong formatting...

Comment: Also XML would be wrong, as that snippet is HTML. Clearly, it's all to see in how many cases XML would be the right assumption, considering that the same language is applied when highlighting code shown in the answers.

Comment: As far as i see, when maven is the first tag used, code snippet are very often xml. Totally agree with you Lukas.

Comment: I agree with Lukas. The vast majority of Maven questions I've encountered relate to XML rather than Java code. In fact, I came here to ask this very question before realising he beat me to it.